# Print a Circular Linked List Recursively

Tags: java, recursion, printing, linked-list

I have been stumped by this question in one of my tutorials:

Given a Circular linked list which has only a tail pointer, write a recursive method with the following header to print out the list recursively starting from the first element:

public void circularPrint()

I could easily do this question had it not stated to print out the list starting from the first element. But I am stumped because of the multiple restrictions that are enforced by this question. Could someone please advise me on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What restrictions cause you problems? Please be more specific. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: The restriction that only the tail pointer is given and also that I have to print out the first element first. I wish to print out the circular list starting from the first element. But I just cannot figure out how because I cannot terminate the loop as I would not know where to stop the iteration using only the tail pointer.

Comment: Pattern to solve all "recursive problems".  1:  pass along into the recursive functions the data you need to decide what to do next.  2:  Define your base case and stop the recursion on that event.  Define the iterative case that moves you toward the end and call the recursive function with necessary divisions of the data.

Comment: @LanceHAOH I answered below. Hope that helps, if not - please don't hesitate to ask further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's circular linked list, that means that the last element (tail) has a field pointing to the first element. So at this moment you also have a head (so to speak).

You can do it for example this way:

1. Print the tail's `next` element (which is the 1-st element).
2. Assign the second element to the tail's next.
3. Repeat.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Doing point 2, you are shortening the list, which eventually will end in tail pointing to itself. You obviously have to make a few checks - if the `next` element exists, etc. I provided you the basic logic, do you expect us to write you whole program? It's your assignment, use the tips and write it yourself! :)

Comment: Oh. I see. So this is actually a destructive printing method. I drew it out to understand the logic. It works but it destroys the entire list.

Comment: You can obviously do the *other* list... if you don't want this to be "destroyed".

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean after looking at the pseudo-code provided by Sylwester.

Answer (score 1):

Is the list only one circle, like a circular buffer? Then you can print until the next pointer is the same as the reference to the list.

If the circles can be in to any previous element then you need to apply one of the [Turtoise  and hare algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

It's quite easy with singly linked lists. Not so easy if you have like Scheme `cons` cells that can have structure in both pointers which would require quite a bit of backtracking and housekeeping.

As for you problem with the method signature I haven't heard of inner methods in Java so you'll need to define a helper. eg.

```
public void circularPrint()
{
  circularPrintAux(this);
}
```

For turoise and hare it would be:

```
public void circularPrint()
{
  if( this.next == this )
      ...
  else
      circularPrintAux(this, this.next);
}
```

Comment: Yes. There is only one circle in the list. How would you print until the next pointer is the same as the reference to the list? You mean keep a temp pointer? But the method header does not accept any parameters.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Ive added some more. Think you need a private helper method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass in two parameters, the current element and the starting element. For your first call, these will be the same. Once you've printed the current element, recursively call on the next element in the list. Only do the recursive call if the next element != the starting element.